# Как рисовать вне onDraw()?

Tags: android, android-canvas, рисование

Попытался сделать так, как сказано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032383/9007098)

Собственно, **код класса**

```
    public class DrawView extends View {

    private Canvas canvas;

    /*
     другие объявления
     */

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        canvas = null;
       //.......
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       //......
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //рисую

        canvas.save();
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

       //определяю место касания и вызываю метод showNameDialog()

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    private void showNameDialog(int x, int y) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
        input.setHint("например, Здоровье");
        alertDialog.setTitle("Новая группа");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Введите название группы");
        alertDialog.setView(input);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            Log.d(MyApplication.TAG, "ok pressed");
            dots[x][y] = !dots[x][y];
            try {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(MyApplication.TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Назад", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Не смотря на то, что сделал вроде бы как и советовали в том вопросе, приложение крашится и само перезапускается (на реальном ус-ве, даже не смотря на то, что находится в блоке `try-catch`) при любых попытках рисовать на `canvas` вне `onDraw()`, то есть если убрать `canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN)` из метода `showNameDialog`, то приложение не падает.